# testing-library unable to see my muiButton

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am using testing-library with MUI button.

My test :

```
  it('Should show more when I click on show more', () => {
    render(<RankedThemes {...props} />);
    expect(screen.getAllByText(/^citations positives$/)).toHaveLength(3);

    fireEvent.click(screen.queryByRole('button', { name: 'Afficher Plus'}));
    expect(screen.getAllByText(/^citations positives$/)).toHaveLength(topPositive.length);
  });
```

My HTML output of the test:

```
 <div
        class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-container css-1hbmzt3-MuiGrid-root"
      >
        <button
          class="MuiButton-root MuiButton-text MuiButton-textPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-textSizeMedium MuiButtonBase-root  css-1throlb-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiButton-root"
          tabindex="0"
          type="button"
        >
          <div>
            <svg
              aria-hidden="true"
              class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium css-i4bv87-MuiSvgIcon-root"
              data-testid="KeyboardArrowDownIcon"
              focusable="false"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            >
              <path
                d="M7.41 8.59 12 13.17l4.59-4.58L18 10l-6 6-6-6 1.41-1.41z"
              />
            </svg>
             
            Afficher plus
          </div>
          <span
            class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-8je8zh-MuiTouchRipple-root"
          />
        </button>
      </div>
```

My error :

```
Error: Unable to fire a "click" event - please provide a DOM element.
```

If i use

```
fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/Afficher Plus/gi));
```

It works well, so i guess "/gi" is doing something. But i would like to use queryByRole because it's cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Give your  an `aria-label` attribute, e.g. `aria-label="my-btn"`, so in your case:

```
<button
          class="MuiButton-root MuiButton-text MuiButton-textPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-textSizeMedium MuiButtonBase-root  css-1throlb-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiButton-root"
          tabindex="0"
          type="button"
          aria-label="my-btn"
        >
```

Then in react-testing-library you can use `getByRole` and specifiy the `name` attribute to grab your button for testing.

```
test("Valentin Garreau's btn ", () => {
                // first make sure react-testing-lib can find it
                expect(screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'my-btn' })).toBeVisible();

                // then test your stuff
                fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'my-btn' }));
                expect( <insert assertion here> )
            });
```

Comment: Good answer here. I'd only add 2 things:

1. Use `userEvent` instead of `fireEvent` as it emulates a real user much better, see https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro#differences-from-fireevent.

2. You will likely have to use `await screen.findBy*` in the `expect( <insert assertion here> )` so that you wait for the previous click action to finish.